# How can I map a null value to Seq.empty in Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have encoded a list of values to a single database column by joining them with a delimiter. This works fine, except when the list is empty. In that case the database column is filled with an empty string, and when mapping back this gives me a Seq("") instead of Seq.empty.

```
implicit val SeqUriColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Seq[Uri], String](
  p => p.map(_.toString).mkString(","),
  s => if (s.isEmpty) Seq.empty else s.split(",").map(Uri(_)).toSeq
)
```

I've worked around this by using an if statement but that feels odd. I've tried using `MappedColumnType.base[Seq[Uri], Option[String]]`, but that didn't compile. I think it requires me to also use an option for the `Seq`, and that's not what I'm looking for.

In essence I want an empty Seq to result in a null value in the db, and to return an empty Seq again when retrieving. How do I do this properly?

Comment: `s.split(",").filterNot(_.isEmpty)`

Comment: @Dima that works for the reading part (cleaner than the if) but it doesn't prevent an empty string in the database.

Comment: Well, I don't "speak slick", so, not sure where you are doing your writing. If it is the `p=>` piece, then you can do something like this there as one of the options: `Some(p).map(_.mkString(",")).filterNot(_.isEmpty).orNull`

Comment: @Dima  lol @ "speaking slick". Your suggestion works, but I was hoping for a cleaner slick way to do it, like they do with Option. I generally hate converting collections to Options, but it seems your suggestion is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if they handle options, you can remove `orNull` from the end :). Also, note, that here you are not really converting a collection to option. You are converting a String to option. Does it make it better? :)